Is it expected that reading a whole table takes too long?
I am trying to perform heavy read operations on cassandra DB to plot some graphs however the request is always getting timed out. As a result I increased all the timeout and tried to manually read the data from cassandra to figure out how much time does it take.
time cqlsh <ip> <port> -e 'select count(*) from mykeyspace.statstablev4'

 count
----------
 22720237

(1 rows)

Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key


real    11m41.496s
user    0m2.130s
sys 0m0.574s

As you can see it is taking more than 11 minutes to read 2.2 million records. My question is : Is this expected?? if Yes isn't this time too long for only read operations??
Some details about my environment

It is a three node setup
[root@ayanakoji-node6 /]# nodetool -p 7200 describecluster
Cluster Information:
    Name: my_cluster
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSnitch
    DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        aa46498d-3e6a-3cf3-b60e-3b1aeedf7a6c: [192.168.161.2, 192.168.161.3, 192.168.161.4]

[root@ayanakoji-node6 /]#


[root@ayanakoji-node6 /]# nodetool -p 7200 info
ID                     : 8dfffc76-d19f-460d-b33f-a6aa809bd45d
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : true
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 2.04 GiB
Generation No          : 1720422987
Uptime (seconds)       : 88761
Heap Memory (MB)       : 2131.41 / 7994.00
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 309.51
Data Center            : datacenter1
Rack                   : rack1
Exceptions             : 0
Key Cache              : entries 50675, size 10.38 MiB, capacity 100 MiB, 3906 hits, 52857 requests, 0.074 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 50 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 297, size 18.56 MiB, capacity 480 MiB, 2510828 misses, 4204550 requests, 0.403 recent hit rate, NaN microseconds miss latency
Percent Repaired       : 52.62493465838013%
Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)
[root@ayanakoji-node6 /]#


[root@ayanakoji-node6 /]# nodetool -p 7200 status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.161.2  2.04 GiB   256          68.1%             8dfffc76-d19f-460d-b33f-a6aa809bd45d  rack1
UN  192.168.161.3  1.87 GiB   256          64.9%             6e9658c5-0bbd-4281-a3bf-2fb1aff6480d  rack1
UN  192.168.161.4  1.89 GiB   256          67.0%             980c749c-e344-476d-ae4a-ead3f17764db  rack1

[root@ayanakoji-node6 /]#


**SCHEMA OF THE TABLE**
cqlsh:mykeyspace> desc statstablev4

CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.statstablev4 (
    key int,
    key2 int,
    key3 text,
    key4 text,
    column1 text,
    column2 int,
    column3 uuid,
    column10 text,
    column4 text,
    column5 text,
    column6 text,
    column7 text,
    column8 text,
    column9 text,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((key, key2, key3, key4), column1, column2, column3)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC, column2 ASC, column3 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statstablev4_column5_idx ON mykeyspace.statstablev4 (column5) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'PREFIX'};
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statstablev4_column4_idx ON mykeyspace.statstablev4 (column4) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'PREFIX'};
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statstablev4_column7_idx ON mykeyspace.statstablev4 (column7) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS'};
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statstablev4_column8_idx ON mykeyspace.statstablev4 (column8) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS'};
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statstablev4_column10_idx ON mykeyspace.statstablev4 (column10) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS'};
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statstablev4_column9_idx ON mykeyspace.statstablev4 (column9) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS'};
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statstablev4_column6_idx ON mykeyspace.statstablev4 (column6) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'PREFIX'};





As you can see it is taking more than 11 minutes to read 2.2 million records. My question is : Is this expected?? if Yes isn't this time too long for only read operations??

tl;dr;
Yes, that sounds about right to me.
Cassandra is a distributed database, which means that it needs to understand the relationship between a requested row of data and its physical location on one or more nodes. When given a query that provides a complete PRIMARY KEY, it can figure that out, and it is quite fast. However, when trying to serve unbound queries (SELECTs without WHERE clauses) it doesn't have the required information to do that.
So when trying to handle a query like that, one node gets picked as a "coordinator." That node becomes responsible for pulling in data from all of the other nodes, assembling the result set, and returning it. That's going to cost a lot of resources (memory, network) and it's not going to be fast.
I see a few options to improve the performance of this process.
First, write an exporter to iterate through all possible combinations of the four partition key components: (key, key2, key3, key4). From a pure Cassandra query perspective, making small individual queries is much faster than trying to pull them all back in one query (which yes, works the opposite of what we've been taught with relational databases).

to plot some graphs

Second, if this is to support a graph database, try re-architecting the process to include a message broker/queue like Pulsar or Kafka. That way you can process any writes to both Cassandra and the graph database. Actually, you should check out Quine, which is a streaming, real-time graph and may help you.
Third, have a look at dsbulk, which is our recommended tool for doing a complete, large-scale dump of a Cassandra cluster. We (at DataStax) actually use it to help our larger customers with various database migration tasks. Highly recommended.

You may find this answer helpful in understanding why counting the entire table in Cassandra is a bad idea and the tools to get it done right.
